# Getting error " JSONP injected script did not invoke callback." using Angular 2 and Server ASP.NET core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, jsonp, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Angular 2 at the client side and on the server side Asp.NET Web API core.

I have made a simple post calls from Angular 2 client to ASP.NET core Web API as shown in the below code.

```
        this.http.
            post("/api/Patient", data, options)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
            res => this.CallBack(res),
            err => this.logError(err));
```

My server side ASP core WebAPI code is as shown below.

```
public IActionResult Post()
{
// I am using EF and inserting to DB
// Till here everything works fine.
return Ok(obj);
}
```

When the post happens we get the below error

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

The data gets inserted but when the object is about to be returned the server just refuses. Also when i went deep in to the error i saw the below.

> "JSONP injected script did not invoke callback."
>   JSONP_ERR_WRONG_METHOD : "JSONP requests must use GET request method."
>   JSONP_HOME

In my local it works and some times it does crash.
I am hosting currently on httpwww.smarterasp.net and on that server this error is frequent.

Any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: this may help https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8153

Comment: Thanks @CoderHawk for help. In that issue they  have JSONP request i am making a JSON request. Not sure why i need to deal with JSONP.

Comment: Could you please cross check, same post request works correctly with postman client??

Comment: Yes it works correctly with PostMan. But thanks for pointing me to use PostMan i am seeing things more clearly. Will investigate and come back. Thanks again.

Comment: Its says could not get any response. Looks like some issue with www.smarterasp.net hosting.

Comment: What response code you're getting? Sometime it happened with 503 Error. You can also verify response using ```Advanced Rest client```, ```Fiddler``` or ```postman```

Comment: @GauravKumarArora i used Postman as suggested by Pankaj parkar but this issue from the side of smarterasp.net now.  I have raised a ticket will follow and try to see what is next.

Comment: So, finally this is problem of host, I bet you're getting 503/504 response. In this case there is no other option besides wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this sounds funny. But the fix as that in the POST rather than returning a object we sent JSON serialized string.

```
public string Post() // <-- this was first a object we changed to string
{
// I am using EF and inserting to DB
// Till here everything works fine.
  return SerializedString;
}
```

We are sure this was due to hosting issues of www.smarterasp.net